# How can configure MathJax to recognize textrm{} in equation when using textcolor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax

I'm trying to make an HTML page from LaTEX document that recently achieve it, I used the following mathjax, script configuration, after the head tag:

```
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>    
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],

  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
    "HTML-CSS": { fonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS": { 
      styles: {".MathJax": {color: "#FF0000 ! important"}} 
    }
  });                 

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
    ["PreProcess",MathJax.Hub],
    ["Reprocess",MathJax.Hub]
 );
</script>
```

When I try to write the following equation:

```
\[
\det A=|A|=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-\textrm{fixation d'une  \textcolor{red}{ligne:}} i=\color{red}{p} \Rightarrow |A|=(-1)^{\color{red}{p}+j}\Delta_{\color{red}{p}j}\\
-\textrm{fixation d'une colonne:  } j=\color{red}{p} \Rightarrow |A|=(-1)^{\color{red}{p}+i}\Delta_{i\color{red}{p}}
\end{array}
\right.
\]
```

The command `textcolor{red}` doesn't work. What can I do it with MathJax to configure it in order to get a colorful text in equation?

This is the result of my compilation:

[image: screen of my compilation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#differences), MathJax does does not focus on textmode and only allows the following within its text-mode macros (`\text{}` etc): `$` for re-entering math mode, `\ref` and `\eqref`.

So there is no way to get anything like `\textcolor` inside `\text` to work.

However, you can wrap `\color` around `\text` to color the text and thus you could define a custom macro `\textwithcolor{red}{some text mode}`, e.g., by using `$\require{color}\newcommand{\textwithColor}[2]{\color{#1}{\text{#2}}} \textwithColor{red}{halleo}$`.

You would still need to drop out of text mode to use it.

FWIW, there is an open [issue for MathJax v3](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3/issues/135) to reconsider macros within text mode.